# Drupal 7 View tab on user profile empty as default?

Tags: users

In a default Drupal 7 installation where no custom fields were been added to user profiles is it the normal behavior that the user profile tab View is empty? I would expect to see for example the registration email. Thank you all for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a page view with path /user/% where I can show any user field I need. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

The user view tab should include the default user entity_view information as per

- [user_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_view/7) and
- [user_build_content](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_build_content/7)

Normally that's information such as the history / length of time since registration and other default content.

Comment: any idea about why I have an empty user profile view tab and how eventually to fix this? Thanks

Comment: History field was disabled in user profile configuration. After enabled I can see it. What about other fields such as registration email and registration date?